# Gamma distribution with error bands - correct?

Tags: data-visualization, fitting, distributions

I currently fitted a gamma distribution onto empirical degree centrality data. I have calculated the standard errors using Fisher information.

As I am just an economist, I am not entirely sure about the mathematical implications. As you can see in the picture, the error bands are crossing around the mean. This makes sense to me, as the standard deviation of the mean should be zero, right? However, the bands cross afterwards. Is this correct?

If I understood the math right, this is due to the e-function in the PDF, but I am not sure about it. Hence, I would be thrilled if someone could tell me if my approach was right, or wrong.

The code:

```
`distemppos = EmpiricalDistribution[dgre2014pos];
posed = EmpiricalDensity[dgre2014pos, Min[dgre2014pos], 
   Max[dgre2014pos], 60, 
   PlotStyle -> {ColorData[1][2], PointSize[0.009]}];
estpos = EstimatedDistribution[dgre2014pos, GammaDistribution[a, b]];
pdfestpos = 
  Plot[PDF[estpos, x], {x, 0, Max[dgre2014pos]}, PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotStyle -> Black];
pdfesttest1 = 
  PDF[GammaDistribution[(3.741317568532157` + \
(2*0.10689677091063837`)), (8.563343712535122` + \
(2*0.26185423681186465`))], x];
pdfesttest2 = 
  PDF[GammaDistribution[(3.741317568532157` - \
(2*0.10689677091063837`)), (8.563343712535122` - \
(2*0.26185423681186465`))], x];
pdfesttest =  Plot[{pdfesttest1, pdfesttest2, pdfestpos}, {x, 
       0, Max[dgre2014pos]}, PlotRange -> All, 
      PlotStyle -> {{Opacity[2/3], ColorData[1][1]}, {Opacity[2/3], 
      ColorData[1][1]}, Black}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}, 
      FillingStyle -> {Opacity[0.15], Opacity[0.15]}];
gamma14 = 
 Show[pdfesttest, pdfestpos, posed, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotStyle -> "Gray", 
  PlotLabel -> 
   "Estimated and Empirical PDF for Degree Distribition 2014", 
  FontSize -> 10, ImageSize -> 500]`
```

The plot:
[image: Gamma plot]

@whuber Thank you very much for your immediate reply. The error bands are the parameters one time plus and one time minus 2 times the standard errors. I have computed them using Fisher information.

THe code looks as follows:

```
`dist = GammaDistribution[a, b];
data = dgre2014pos;

est = FindDistributionParameters[data, dist]
standarderrors[data_, dist_, paramlist_, mleRule_] := 
 Block[{len, infmat, cov}, len = Length[data];
  (*compute negative of expected Fisher information*)
  infmat = -D[LogLikelihood[dist, data], {paramlist, 2}]/len /. 
    mleRule;
  (*invert to get asymptotic covariance for Sqrt[n](theta-theta0)*)
  cov = Inverse[infmat];
  (*standard errors are the Sqrt of diagonal elements divided by \
sample size*)Sqrt[Diagonal[cov]/len]]

standarderrors[data, dist, {a, b}, est]`
```

@JimBaldwin Thank you for your comment. Would it be possible to maybe explain how I can take the joint distribution of the parameter estimators into consideration?

Comment: So that we don't have to decipher your code (which seems almost irrelevant--isn't it just graphing stuff?), could you please explain what these "error bands" are intended to represent and describe how you are computing them?

Comment: (1) You should follow @whuber 's advice but put the clarification (in words and not in code) in the above question and NOT in the comments.  (2) It appears that you think that for a two-parameter model one evaluates the density at the upper confidence bound for both parameters and the lower confidence bound for both parameters.  This works fine for single parameter models but not otherwise.  One needs to take into consideration the joint distribution of the parameter estimators.

Comment: Thank you @JimBaldwin. I changed my entry accordingly. Please find my question at the end of the revised post. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you want to be able to construct confidence bands for the gamma probability density function.  My guess is that the data you used had about 2,500 observations based on the standard errors for the parameters that you display.

Given that you've started this using *Mathematica*, here are two approaches that might be useful.

First, generate some data:

```
n = 2500;
data = RandomVariate[GammaDistribution[3.7, 8.6], n];
```

**Delta method**

```
(* Construct log of the likelihood *)
logL = LogLikelihood[GammaDistribution[a, b], data];

(* Get maximum likelihood estimates of the parameters along with an estimate
   of the covariance matrix of the parameter estimators *)
sol = FindMaximum[{logL, a > 0 && b > 0}, {{a, 4}, {b, 9}}]
cov = -Inverse[(D[logL, {{a, b}, 2}]) /. sol[[2]]]

(* Using the Delta Method estimate the standard error of the log of 
   the density function at a particular value x *)
partial = D[Log[PDF[GammaDistribution[a, b], x][[1, 1, 1]]], {{a, b}}];
se = (partial.cov.partial /. sol[[2]])^0.5;

(* Plot the estimated density and the approximate 95% confidence limits *)
g = PDF[GammaDistribution[a, b] /. sol[[2]], x][[1, 1, 1]]
Plot[{g, Exp[Log[g] + 1.96 se], Exp[Log[g] - 1.96 se]}, {x, 0, 250},
 PlotStyle -> {Black, Gray, Gray}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Density function with 95% confidence intervals]

**Bootstrap**

As an alternative one could take random samples with replacement from your data and construct zillions of estimates of the density along a grid of x values.  One could find the 2.5 and 97.5 percentiles and connect those to construct the confidence band.

```
(* Get maximum likelihood estimates as before *)
logL = LogLikelihood[GammaDistribution[a, b], data];
sol = FindMaximum[{logL, a > 0 && b > 0}, {{a, 4}, {b, 9}}];
g = PDF[GammaDistribution[a, b] /. sol[[2]], x][[1, 1, 1]];

nBoot = 1000;  (* Number of bootstrap samples *)
(* Array to hold results for values of x from 1 to 250 *)
pdf = ConstantArray[0, {nBoot, 250}];
Do[
 (* Bootstrap sample *)
 boot = RandomChoice[data, n];

 (* Construct log of the likelihood *)
 logL = LogLikelihood[GammaDistribution[a, b], boot];

 (* Get maximum likelihood estimates of the parameters along with an estimate
 of the covariance matrix of the parameter estimators *)
 sol = FindMaximum[{logL, a > 0 && b > 0}, {{a, 4}, {b, 9}}][[2]];
 (* Add to the bootstrap results *)
 pdf[[i]] = PDF[GammaDistribution[a, b], #] /. sol & /@ Range[1, 250],
 {i, nBoot}]

(* Construct percentiles for each value of x along the grid *)
lowerCL = Table[Quantile[pdf[[All, j]], 0.025], {j, 250}];
upperCL = Table[Quantile[pdf[[All, j]], 0.975], {j, 250}];

(* Plot results *)
Show[Plot[g, {x, 0, 250}, PlotStyle -> Black, PlotRange -> All],
 ListPlot[{lowerCL, upperCL}, Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> Gray]]
```

[image: Bootstrap confidence bands for gamma distribution]

Both techniques seem to have very similar results (in this case).  Also note that we are assuming a gamma distribution and any deviations from that not considered.  So these approaches are conditional on assuming a random sample from a gamma distribution.

Comment: Wow! This answer is brilliant! Thank you very much for your extensive explanations and the code. Awesome, @Jim Baldwin.